# Run -> Debug not appearing in Code Composer Studio

Tags: msp430, code-composer

I just started programming with Code Composer Studio. I am using MSP430G2553 MCU. I followed [this](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/getting-started-with-msp430-using-code-composer-studio) tutorial, added code to toggle LED and built the project to which I got following output:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project Float Precision ****

"C:\\ti\\ccsv8\\utils\\bin\\gmake" -k -j 4 all -O 

gmake[1]: 'Float Precision.out' is up to date.

**** Build Finished ****
```

After this I am supposed to click on 'Run -> Debug'. However, all options in Run menu are grayed out. I see following:

[image: Options are grayed out]

I am not able to find any links online to explain this. Can anyone help?

My ultimate goal is to create a simple floating point addition program to understand how MSP430 handles floating point arithmetic.

Comment: That tutorial contains errors (e.g., there is an inbuilt delay function: `__delay_cycles`). But it does mention the case that these options are blanked out.

Comment: @CL. Already tried 'View -> Debug', which does nothing except bring up these grayed out options. Can you refer me to a better tutorial?

Comment: http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Category:Code_Composer_Studio_v8, or ask on e2e.ti.com.

Comment: @CL. Thank you.